# setWebViewClient error - someView(context) in someView cannot be applied to ()

Tags: java, android, webview, android-context

I´m sorry if this is a dumb question. Im a beginner at this. I have two Java files. in `ourViewClient.java` I had to make this Context thing.

```
public class ourViewClient extends WebViewClient {

Context context;


public ourViewClient (Context c){
    this.context = c;
}`
```

I don´t know what it does but it made an error in my MainActivity.java where i am using this code `browser.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient());` The error message is  "**ourViewClient(Context) in ourViewClient cannot be applied to ()**".

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared one constructor on `ourViewClient`. It takes a `Context` as a parameter. Hence, `new ourViewClient()` needs a `Context` as a parameter.

Comment: you mean like `new ourViewClient(Context)`? that gives me "expression expected"

Comment: @Stumpp: No, I mean that you need to pass in an instance of some object that is from a class that inherits from `Context`. **Please** take the time to learn Java. I have [a list of Wikibooks entries](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/02/java-good-parts-version.html) representing the key areas of Java that Android developers need to know. There are also plenty of other Java educational resources on the Internet and elsewhere.

Comment: Yes i guess i should start with some basics. I managed to fix the error now so thanks:)